# Setting DNS for a Virtual Host on Same IP

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, virtualhost

I have multiple domains hosted on one server with just one IP address, it was previously setup by other people and past on to me and I have had to change Domain Providers and have to setup the DNS settings for the server.

The main website mainsite.example.com has been successfully setup to work with its domain, by setting the CNAME for the domain to mainsite.example.com and a @ record to the IP address.

Now am trying to setup the other website which doesn't show up on mainsite.example.com or other alias, but am struggling to get the DNS settings right for this domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add A records for each new site to that same IP.

```
newsite.com. IN A 192.168.2.10
```

basically the setup for the first domain, with the new domain name switched in but the IP the same, should work. The DNS points them all to the same place and the web server sorts them out in the VirtualHost directives.

Comment: Ok on the 123-reg control panel I have added... 

example2.co.uk/com to the DNS settings of the www.mainsite.co.uk/com  they are pointing to the IP address so hopefully this will work :)

Comment: it is perfectly legit to have multiple A records pointing to the same IP.